# LDAP users to share a single SFTP folder on Linux

Tags: linux, active-directory, sftp

I need to setup a file transfer linux server. All users login via sftp using active directory credentials.

I want all users to when logged into see a single directory /ftp-storage

In the /ftp-storage folder will be a number of other project folders for each proejct

```
/ftp-storage
  /project1
  /project2
```

I want all users when logging in with sftp to land in the /ftp-storage folder.
Access to the project folders will limited by the AD groups the users are in which I can sort out.

I just don't know how to force all users to land in the /ftp-storage folder and not their linux home directory when logging in with filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer elsewhere.
I added the following code /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```bash
Match group <ad-group>@<domain.com>
ChrootDirectory /ftp-storage
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Where  is the name of the group on active directory i.e. (sftp) and <domain.com> is the name of the AD Domain.

I then gave the following permissions

```
chmod root:sftp@domain.com -R /ftp-storage
chmod root:project2@domain.com -R /ftp-storage/project2
chmod root:project3@domain.com -R /ftp-storage/project3
```

Now when users login, if they are in the sftp AD Group they land in /ftp-storage and not their home directory and they can only access the projects that they are a member of in the relevant AD Groups.